# Entity Framework 7 RC1 adding nested child entities results in wrong mapping

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Adding a (medium) large quantity of nested child entities through the Entity Framework 7 (Release Candidate 1) stores wrong entity->child-entity mappings.

Simplified example to reproduce the issue:

```
using (TestContext dbContext = new TestContext())
{
    var nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 40);

    var orders = nums.Select(s => new TestOrder()
    {
        name = s.ToString(),
        TestOrderItem = nums.Take(10).Select(o => new TestOrderItem()
        {
            name = (s*100 + o).ToString(),
            TestOrderPricing =
                new[] {new TestOrderPricing() {amount = (s*100 + o), PricingType = "Principal"}}.ToList()
        }).ToList()

    });


    dbContext.AddRange(orders);

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

*After executing that, all the relations are stored - but most of the TestPricing entities are referencing a wrong TestOrderItem-entity.*

**Is this an existing bug of the Entity Framework RC1 or do I have a wrong setup?**

**Setup for the Test-Environment:**

- Visual Studio 2015
- DNX 4.6
- EF7 RC1

1) Database first - creating the 3 tables:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestOrder](
    [OrderId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Order] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestOrderItem](
    [OrderItemId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OrderId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderItem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderItemId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestOrderPricing](
    [OrderItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PricingType] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [amount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderPricing] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderItemId] ASC,
    [PricingType] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestOrderItem]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderItem_Order] FOREIGN KEY([OrderId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TestOrder] ([OrderId])
ON DELETE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestOrderItem] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderItem_Order]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestOrderPricing]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderPricing_OrderItem] FOREIGN KEY([OrderItemId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TestOrderItem] ([OrderItemId])
ON DELETE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestOrderPricing] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderPricing_OrderItem]
```

2) Scaffolding the model

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=.;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer --outputDir Models
```

3) Run the example

Or download the console application with mapping included:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=352A0129BF9CBD17%2134155

Observations:

- If I don't use serverside generated identity keys there is no issue
- Adding `entity.Property(e => e.OrderItemId).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn()` (which is not added by scaffolding) does not help
- Setting on each child entity the reference-property to the parent-entity does not help
- With the adding of fewer entities there is no issue

Comment: If you think it is a bug in EF you may want to file it here: github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I don't know I it is a bug in EF7 RC... It would be a quite serious one for RC - and rare that it has been never detected before - because adding nested child entities with identity keys is a quite common use case in my opinion...

Comment: `nums.Take(10)` is functionally equivalent to `Enumerable.Range(1, 10)` in your example. Are you sure this is intentional?

Comment: That's not the point, but you will get the same - not working - result with `Enumberable.Range(1, 10)`, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed issue in RC1, verified that this is fixed in working code base and the fix will ship in RC2